# Count no me regresa conteo total si no varios conteos en si

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta el cuál cuento el total de registros que tengo en mi tabla pero este no me devuelve un valor total si no varios conteos totales, lo que quiero es que me muestre un total general y no desglosado.

**Lo quiero así:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pero me lo devuelve así:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta:

```
SELECT count(*) AS numrows from facturas f JOIN clientes c JOIN users u JOIN medicos m JOIN detalle_factura d JOIN productos p ON f.id_cliente = c.id_cliente AND f.id_vendedor = u.user_id AND f.id_medico = m.id_medico AND d.id_producto = p.id_producto AND d.numero_factura = f.numero_factura GROUP BY c.id_cliente,f.numero_factura order by f.fecha_factura desc
```

**Si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho.**

Comment: hola @Triby si lo quito pero no me da el total que es me da otra cantidad 8715 en vez de los 3238 y no se por que sera.

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas los JOIN si solo estás contando los registros de una tabla y solo obtienes una columna?

Comment: entonces como lo aplico amigo sin los join?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres solo el total de facturas, entonces la consulta debe ser solo:

```
SELECT count(*) AS numrows from facturas
```

Si quieres el total de detalle:

```
SELECT count(*) AS numrows from detalle_factura
```

Si quieres otro total, entonces especifica exactamente lo que quieres obtener y cuáles deben ser los filtros (vendedor, cliente, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo un group by por lo que el resultado que te muestra es el conteo por cada uno de esos datos agrupados.

Un saludo

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).